# null pointer exception in my bubblesort, and other sort methods

Tags: java, linked-list, nullpointerexception, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

I have a project where I have to write a bunch of sort methods and measure the time complexity for each, and output the results to an output text file. the program runs but i get some null pointer exceptions in bubblesort method. here is my code and error, if you can tell me how to fix my sort methods, that would be awesome!

linked list class:

```
public class LinkedList {
protected static class Node {
    Comparable item;
    Node prev, next;

    public Node(Comparable newItem, Node prev, Node next) {
        this.item = newItem;
        this.prev = prev;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node (Comparable newItem) {
        this(newItem, null, null);
    }

    public Node() {
        this(null, null, null);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(item);
    }
}

private Node head;
private int size;
public int dataCompares, dataAssigns;
public int loopCompares, loopAssigns;
public int other;

public LinkedList() {
    head = new Node(null, null, null);
    head.prev = head;
    head.next = head;
    size = 0;
}

public boolean add(Comparable newItem) {
    Node newNode = new Node(newItem);
    Node curr;
    if(isEmpty()) {
        head.next = newNode;
        head.prev = newNode;
        newNode.next = head;
        newNode.prev = head;
    } else {
        newNode.next = head;
        newNode.prev = head.prev;
        head.prev.next = newNode;
        head.prev = newNode;
    }
    size++;
    return false;
}

public boolean remove(Comparable item) {
    if(!isEmpty()) {
        Node prev = null;
        Node curr = head;
        while(curr!=null) {
            if(curr.item.compareTo(item)==0) {
                if(prev==null) {
                    head=curr.next;
                } else {
                    prev.next = curr.next;
                    curr=curr.next;
                }
                size--;
                return true;
            }else{
                prev=curr;
                curr = curr.next;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public void removeAll() {
    this.head.prev = null;
    this.head.next = null;
    size = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

public boolean remove(Object item) {
    return true;
}

public void insertSortNode() {  
    Node back = head;
if (size < 2)
    return;
    back = back.next;           // SECOND entry in the list
    while ( back != null ) {      // I.e., end-of-list
           Comparable value = back.item;
        Node curr = head;        // Start at the front
  // Find insertion point for value;
    while (curr != back && value.compareTo(curr.item) >= 0)
            curr = curr.next;
  // Propogate values upward, inserting the value from back
    while (curr != back){  
            Comparable hold = curr.item;
        curr.item = value;
        value = hold;
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    back.item = value;      // Drop final value into place!
    back = back.next;       // Move sorted boundary up
}
} // end insertSort()

       public void selSort() {  
    Node front = head;
   // Nothing to do on an empty list
      if ( front == null )
         return;
      while ( front.next != null ) {     // skips a one-entry list
         Node tiny = front;
         Node curr = front.next;
         Comparable temp = front.item; // start the swap
         for ( ; curr != null ; curr = curr.next ) {  
                if ( tiny.item.compareTo(curr.item) > 0 )
                tiny = curr;
         }
         front.item = tiny.item;       // Finish the swap
         tiny.item = temp;
         front = front.next;           // Advance to the next node
      }
      // The structure is unchanged, so the validity of tail is unchanged.
       }


public void bubbleSort() {
    Node Trav=head.next;
    Node Trail=head.next;
    Comparable temp;
    if (Trav != null)
       Trav = Trav.next;
    while(Trav!=null) {
      if (Trav.item.compareTo(Trail.item)<0) {
        temp = Trail.item;
        Trail.item=Trav.item;
        Trav.item = temp;
      }
      Trail=Trav;
      Trav=Trav.next;
    }
   }

public void insertSortArray() {
    Node insert1, cur, tmp1;
    Comparable temp;
    for(insert1 = this.head.next.next; insert1!=this.head; insert1 = insert1.next) {
    //++loopcompares; ++loopassigns;
        for (cur = head.next; cur!=insert1; cur=cur.next) {
        //++loopCompares; ++loopassigns;
        //++datacompares;
            if(insert1.item.compareTo(cur.item)<0) {
                temp=insert1.item;
                //++dataassign
                tmp1=insert1;
                //++other
                while(tmp1!=cur.prev) {
                //++loopcomares
                    tmp1.item=tmp1.prev.item;
                    tmp1=tmp1.prev;
                    //++dataassign+=2
                }
                //++loopcompares
                cur.item = temp;
                //++dataassign;
                break;
            }
        }
        //++loopcompares; ++loopassigns;
    }
    //++loopcompares; ++loopassigns
}

public void disp6sortsFile(boolean disp, String fileName, String header, String data) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    PrintWriter pw = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("File open failed for " +fileName+ "\n" + e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    if (disp) {
        pw.print(header + "\n");
    }
        pw.print(data + "\n");
        pw.close();
}
}
```

here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedList.bubbleSort(LinkedList.java:149)
    at LinkListTester.main(LinkListTester.java:51)
```

the linkedlisttester error is simply list1.bubbleSort(); so bubble sort is the problem.

Comment: Please post the exception and stack trace and indicate which line in your source code it is being thrown from. And I don't mean a line number either.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not going to read all that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/158667)

Comment: What is `Comparable`? Is it the standard Java interface, or a user defined class?

Comment: i re edited the question and provided the error. sorry bout that guys. im new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.item.toString();
}
```

to:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(item); // Handle null too.
}
```

For `add` return true. Might check that item is not null if so desired.

**`remove` is written for a single linked list.**

In `remove` the head has a null item, which might have caused the error. Also as we have a circular list with a dummy node for head, the termination should not test for null but head. Otherwise a not present item will loop infinitely.

```
public boolean remove(Comparable item) {
if(!isEmpty()) {
    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = head.next; // !
    while(curr!=head) { // !
        if(curr.item.compareTo(item)==0) {
            if(prev==null) { // ! WRONG, but I will not correct home work ;)
                head=curr.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = curr.next;
                curr=curr.next;
            }
            size--;
            return true;
        }else{
            prev=curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

swap is written for a single linked list.

And here I stopped reading, as I've come to the usages.

---

***Second Edit:***

All algorithmic functions, i.e. bubbleSort, have the following control flow:

```
while(Trav!=null) { ... Trav = Trav.next; }
```

But the data structure is defined cyclic, so eventually you arrive back at `head` and there the item is null.

**The solution is to have for the first Node a prev null, and for the last Node a next null.**

To make this clear, readable, you could substitute the `Node head` with:

```
Node first;
Node last;
```

Comment: well the remove method was given to us by the professor, so ill have a word with him

Comment: check the edits to the question. bubbleSort is what my error is. remove isnt really used.

Comment: Sorry, there is a divergence in conception of (1) data structure + insert, (2) the rest. Extended the answer. Didn't grasp that you should change (1).

Comment: i cant change head. thats a requirement. i was given the linked list class and had to add the sorting methods. thank you for that suggestion but if i do that i lose points :/

Comment: Okay `head` can remain, but in `add` the statement `newNode.next = head;` creates a cyclic list, without end.